# String Type getting input from user with 'space'

Tags: c++, string, whitespace

i`m trying to get a string handler which takes input from user in a string type variable... but it is crashing and i would like to know why? or what am i doing wrong...

```
 string UIconsole::getString(){
    string input;
    getline(cin,input);
    if(input.empty() == false){
        return input;
    }
    else{getString();}
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
error:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

Comment: Disregarding the fact that I doubt this code does what you want it to do, what kind of crash are you experiencing?

Comment: Crashing where - in this code? When it returns? In code that uses the result of this function? Do you have a line number and / or a stack trace? Crashes with what error / exception?

Comment: lots and lots of prints of the menu :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of errors, but the specific one that the message refers to is this:

```
return 0;
```

You can't construct a `std::string` from a null pointer. If you want an empty string, try one of these contstructs:

```
return "";
return std::string();
```

---

Your other error is the recursive call to `getString()`. It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do there. Maybe this does what you want:

```
// untested
std::string UIconsole::getString(){
    std::string input;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, input) && input.empty()) {
        // nothing
    }
    return input;
}
```